Determine corner coordinates and Draw contours in OpenCV
Binary mask:

Expected image:

I am working on OpenCV-Python and I have an binary image below.
Next I have an "expected" image that has the contours on it. In this example image, it has 5 polygon (rectangle) contours with total of 20-coordiante corners (I painted the contours for the "expected" image for visualisation).
This is my code but it can find just 16 corners :
import cv2
import numpy as np
filename = 'train_data/label/1112.jpg'
inputImage = cv2.imread(filename)
inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()
grayInput = cv2.cvtColor(inputImageCopy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayInput, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cannyImage = cv2.Canny(binaryImage, 120, 255, 1)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(cannyImage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cornerList = []

for i, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Approximate the contour to a polygon:
    contoursPoly = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)

    # Convert the polygon to a bounding rectangle:
    boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(contoursPoly)

    # Get the bounding rect's data:
    rectX = boundRect[0]
    rectY = boundRect[1]
    rectWidth = boundRect[2]
    rectHeight = boundRect[3]

    # Estimate the bounding rect area:
    rectArea = rectWidth * rectHeight

    # Set a min area threshold
    minArea = 1000
    if rectArea > minArea:

        hull = cv2.convexHull(c)
        # Create image for good features to track:
        (height, width) = cannyImage.shape[:2]
        # Black image same size as original input:
        hullImg = np.zeros((height, width), dtype =np.uint8)
        # Draw the points:
        cv2.drawContours(hullImg, [hull], 0, 255, 2)
        cv2.imshow("hullImg", hullImg)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        maxCorners = 4
        qualityLevel = 0.01
        minDistance = 0.01 * int(max(height, width) / maxCorners)

        corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(hullImg, maxCorners, qualityLevel, minDistance = minDistance)
        if corners is not None:
            corners = np.intp(corners)
            for c in corners:
                (x, y) = c.ravel()
                cornerList.append((x, y))
        else:
            print("No corners found for the current contour.")
len(cornerList)

And the next is the code to print the (x,y) coordinates and save it to a .txt file :
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def calculate_centroid(points):
    x_coords = [p[0] for p in points]
    y_coords = [p[1] for p in points]
    _len = len(points)
    centroid_x = sum(x_coords) / _len
    centroid_y = sum(y_coords) / _len
    return (centroid_x, centroid_y)

def find_nearest_polygon(polygons, centroid):
    centroids = [calculate_centroid(p[1]) for p in polygons]
    distances = cdist([centroid], centroids)
    return np.argmin(distances)

def group_and_merge_corners(corners, min_corners_per_polygon=4):
    grouped = []
    small_groups = []
    for i in range(0, len(corners), min_corners_per_polygon):
        polygon_corners = corners[i:i + min_corners_per_polygon]
        if len(polygon_corners) == min_corners_per_polygon:
            centroid = calculate_centroid(polygon_corners)
            grouped.append((centroid, polygon_corners))
        else:
            small_groups.append(polygon_corners)

    # Merge small polygons into the nearest full polygon
    for small_group in small_groups:
        small_centroid = calculate_centroid(small_group)
        nearest_idx = find_nearest_polygon(grouped, small_centroid)
        grouped[nearest_idx][1].extend(small_group)

    return grouped

merged_groups = group_and_merge_corners(cornerList)

with open('output1112.txt', 'w') as file:
    for idx, group in enumerate(merged_groups):
        # Only print if there are at least 4 points after merging
        if len(group[1]) >= 4:
            file.write(f"0 {' '.join(str(coord) for point in group[1] for coord in point)}\n")
    

But then what I received is just a .txt file with 16 corners

How to determine the corner coordinates of the contours and save it to a .txt file because I will use it to train on YOLO. Then how to draw contours for the binary image like the "expected" image.
Thank you so much for your help !

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78348232/convert-binary-mask-images-to-polygonal-segmentation-with-yolo-annotation-format
